# Setting a boolean for a group of FKs

Tags: mysql

In my table, I have a PK, an FK, a number, and a flag, like this:

```
tableID | PK of table
refID   | FK to another table
phoneNo | Phone number
default | Flag for default number
```

Sample of data:

```
tableID|refID|phoneNo|default
-------+-----+-------+-------
1      |23   |1234567|0
2      |23   |4987546|0
3      |23   |6576546|1
4      |24   |3289832|0
5      |24   |5225454|0
6      |24   |9126386|0
7      |25   |3287293|1
```

As you can see, ID 23 and 25 have default phone numbers, but ID 24 doesn't.

I want to write something that lets me check if a `refID` has a default number.
If they don't have a default number, make the first one the default number (in this case, `tableID` 4 would become a default number).

What would the query for that look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
UPDATE table1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT MIN(tableID) AS tableID 
  FROM table1 
  WHERE refID NOT IN (SELECT refID FROM table1 WHERE `default` = 1)
  ) AS minrows ON table1.tableID = minrows.tableID
SET table1.`default` = 1;
```

This would set`default=1`for the first row for each RefID that doesn't already have a row with`default=1`.

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c7185/1)